# Height 0 on Body

Tags: html, css, sass, height

I always get *height: 0* on the body, Why this happens?

Either I use **height, min-height, etc.**

[image]

Comment: Is there any content? If not, then the html height is 0, and 100% of 0 is still 0.

Comment: use height :100% instead of min-height

Comment: if html has not height:100%; set, then it is min-height:100% of null ;)

Comment: @JonStirling, Yes, body has height: 100%, as a div-container inside with height: 100% too ... and inside container, I have header and footer, all absolute position

Comment: But do you have any content? As I said, 100% of 0 is still 0. If there's nothing pushing the bottom down, then you will have 0 height.

Comment: contents as well inside absolute positioned divs of header and footer @JonStirling

Comment: The please show more of your markup and SASS / CSS. (Not screenshots please.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use:

```
body{
   height:100vh;
}
```

This will force the body to 100% viewport height regardless of the page contents.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about 'vh', now i will get informed

Comment: This is a terrible advice, you're explicitly setting the body's height to 100vh. Use `min-height: 100vh` instead.

Comment: I am sure there is a good reason for what seems to be a convoluted design but +1 for sharing the knowledge. I looked it up: height: 100vh = 100% of the viewport height. height: 100% = 100% of the parent's element height.

Answer (score 0):

Height = 0 because the parent of the elements have 0 height, so make sure your parent, which is body here have 100% height or else.

```
body {
  height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because of parent height is 0. Follow these styles up!

```
html{
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
} 

body{
    height: 100%;
}
```